# DC.js heatmap cols and rows filtering not working

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a heatmap which for some reason doesn't let me select rows and cols. I can select individual boxes, but the selection isn't visible (ie. other boxes aren't grayed-out)
The code is almost a copy-paste from [the example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/heat.html), but is part of 4 other graphs.
I'm using v2.1.0-dev (~2 days old from Github)

I read somewhere that it might have to do with the scales needing to be ordinal, but I'm not sure how I can set that in a heatmap...

My heatmap code:

```
var dayBurnChart = dc.heatMap("#day-heat-map");
var dayDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return [+d.DayWeek, +d.Week]});
var dayTotal = dayDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return +d.afzet;});

dayBurnChart
    .width(450).height(250)
    .dimension(dayDim)
    .group(dayTotal)
    .keyAccessor(function(d) {return +d.key[0];})
    .valueAccessor(function(d) {return +d.key[1];})
    .colorAccessor(function(d) {return +parseFloat(d.value).toFixed(2);})
    .colsLabel(function(d) {return weekNames[d]; })
    .colors(["#ffffd9","#edf8b1","#c7e9b4","#7fcdbb","#41b6c4","#1d91c0","#225ea8"])
    .calculateColorDomain();
```

Some Data:

```
var data = [
    {"date": "1-10-2015",   "afzet": 603.58},
    {"date": "2-10-2015",   "afzet": 523.25},
    {"date": "3-10-2015",   "afzet": 392.92},
    {"date": "4-10-2015",   "afzet": 420.5},
    {"date": "5-10-2015",   "afzet": 574.66},
    {"date": "6-10-2015",   "afzet": 478.03},
    {"date": "7-10-2015",   "afzet": 586.3},
    {"date": "8-10-2015",   "afzet": 539.46}
];
```

Date Parser:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%m-%Y").parse;
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.Day = d.date.getDate();
    // Get day of the week, start at Monday (=1)
    d.DayWeek = d.date.getDay();
      if(d.DayWeek === 0){d.DayWeek = 7}
    d.Week = d.date.getWeekNumber();
});
var ndx = crossfilter(data);

Date.prototype.getWeekNumber = function(){
    var d = new Date(+this);
    d.setHours(0,0,0);
    d.setDate(d.getDate()+4-(d.getDay()||7));
    return Math.ceil((((d-new Date(d.getFullYear(),0,1))/8.64e7)+1)/7);
};
```

Comment: Your code looks good at a glance. Are you able to create a fiddle we can help you debug? It would be nice to have an example of a calendar heatmap in dc.js, so let's get this working!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0xa1u8f3/10/ but it doesnt work... I have actually never seen a jsfiddle with dc.js work... :(

Comment: it definitely works but there are some kinks. i have a [blank fiddle for the dependencies](http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/u57bfje8/) but i should post one with a basic chart & data. will do so tomorrow and take a look at your code.

Comment: Your example seems to totally work? I just had to add a `dc.renderAll()` to get it to show. Maybe you were missing the css in your original? Here's [my fork](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/pepLf0r9/).

Comment: Great find on the `dc.renderAll()`. But this doesn't make sense :( Let me check what's different between this code and mine...

Comment: Definitely sounds like you're missing dc.css or you have the wrong version, since that's [how deselected boxes are styled](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/dc.css#L319-L323).

Comment: Hi @puredevotion, if you've figured it out, would you mind posting a short answer? It seems like something other people will run into.

Comment: hi @Gordon , sorry, got distracted with other things at the office. It was indeed a stupid error. Apparently there's an old version of Crossfilter in Bower. Replaced it with the web-version and was ready to go!

Comment: Weird, I would never had guessed that. Crossfilter has been stable for a long time. Good to know!